# How to download an older jar of the current project in Gradle

Tags: gradle

The goal is to apply the `japicmp` library through the `japicmp-gradle-plugin` in order to check binary compatibility with a baseline version.

I have tried to create a `Configuration`, adding the `baseline` dependency (the baseline version being set in `gradle.properties` to it. But during build, it always resolves to the freshly built jar.

Here is a summary of what I have:

```
configurations {
    baseline
}

dependencies {
    baseline("GROUP:ARTIFACT:${compatibleVersion}") {
        transitive = false
        force = true
    }
}

task japicmp(type: JapicmpTask) {
    oldClasspath = configurations.baseline
    //...
}

//also tried with a copy task:
task downloadBaseline(type: Copy) {
    src = configurations.baseline
    dst = "$buildDir/baselineLibs/"
}
```

Any idea welcome !